# Does Python have a standard implementation of a Univese set?

Tags: python, set

An implementation of a set that would be a superset of all sets is useful in many cases. At the very least implementation of such a class should always return True in this case:

```
assert <any-value> in UniverseSet()
```

Is there a standard implementation of a universe set in Python?

If there is no standard implementation, is there a 3rd party library that implements it? How would you implement one?

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. There is no answer about a standard implementation. Also the question that you pointed to does not even provides a full set implementation.

Comment: The answer is "no" then.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. How is **no** a useful answer? I voted to reopen. The other answer is not optimized for subset tests (only single elements), and doesn't mention the possibility of having a domain for the universal set (avoiding TypeErrors)

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: then I suggest you add an answer to the other question. The post here is far narrower, as the OP insisted. There is no *standard implementation*.

Comment: I've extended the scope of the question.

Comment: *is there a 3rd party library that implements it?* makes your question off-topic, *How would you implement one?* makes your question too broad.

Comment: @IvanMushketyk: you cannot explicitly ask for external resources, that's off-topic. You'll have to be a *lot* more detailed as to behaviour you expect of a universal set beyond the containment test returning `True`.

Comment: what is a UniverseSet?

Comment: @vaultah, let's be fair, half of the questions we answer everyday are off-topic or too broad, and we still answer them. On the other hand, I'd suggest the OP to close the question and reformulate it giving some more feedback of what is needed.

Comment: @IvanMushketyk I'm sorry for this. Don't let it frustrate you. Create another question, title it: "Good implementation of Universal Set in python", and ask for advice on writing it. Post a comment here when it's done, and I'll find it

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: take into account people like to see research and code effort. Just asking for an implementation is not going to go down well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the original question was too narrow for you. After an edit, it was too broad. If he opens another one, people won't take it well. **How is this person supposed to get your help?** Don't you find that **the question is interesting, google-reachable and useful?**

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: you have 20k and you still don't know how this site works? And please don't misinterpret my words, I never said the question was too narrow.

Comment: The answer, as it has being repeated once and again, is "no, there is nothing like that in the standard library". As to how could you implement it, the answer in the post referred above is the answer. Therefore either the answer is "no" or the answer is "this question is duplicate". Google-reachable doesn't mean I should bother looking what the UniversalSet was, which the OP could have possibly clarified.